# API - Customer ID is not easy to find - please support my_customer

Tags: google-cloud-identity

The new Cloud Identity Groups API is great - now our customers can pick from their groups without needing admin roles.
However they need to know the customer ID, which afaik can only be found in the control panel.
The Admin SDK allows us to use "...the alias my_customer to represent your account's customerId..."
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users
Please can we have the same for the new API?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the customer ID using the [organizations.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/list) API without needing admin roles. It's the `directoryCustomerId` field.